# AUTOSAR BOOLEAN Size is how many bits

Tags: autosar

I find BOOLEAN bit size can be 1 at one Spec while as another I find it to be 8.
Question is which one is correct?
Can I define BOOLEAN bit size as 1 and it will not violate any AUTOSAR Spec?
[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: it's unclear what your programming question is. Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]

Comment: Based on the requirement [PRS_SOMEIP_00065] defining a 1 bit boolean would be in violation of implementing the SOMEIP

Comment: @David Makogon -- This question was not about Source Code but specifically about AUTOSAR Specification related and hence I attached specific snippets so that people understand why am I asking it.
As you can see below, Uwe Honekamp has provided exact answer and some rationale
Hope you understood the context now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bit-addressable memory to store a 1-bit boolean and define the platform data type accordingly. This is not contradicting the SOME/IP specification, which is about bus layout and where booleans have a standardised size of 8 bits.

In other words, the 1-bit boolean from memory can be serialized by a SOME/IP transformer as an 8-bit boolean on the bus, and vice versa.